# OCaml - list of lists recursive 'if expression'

Tags: if-statement, recursion, ocaml, nested-lists

I want to create a rec function, say `oddleninLdbl`, that takes as an argument a list of lists **"L"** and returns a copy of **"L"** in which the lists of odd length have been "doubled" - *doubled here means the list will concatenate with itself.*

To illustrate the above, the idea is to have this :

```
oddleninLdbl [[]; [5]; [23;5]; [45;65;2]; []; [34;85;7;22;1]];;
```

returns the following:

```
[[]; [5;5]; [23;5]; [45;65;2;45;65;2]; []; [34;85;7;22;1;34;85;7;22;1]]
```

it should also work with whatever list type, again for example this here with strings:

```
oddleninLdbl [[]; ["mi";"lo"]; ["la"]; ["lo";"co";"mo"]]
```

should return:

```
[[]; ["mi";"lo"]; ["la";"la"]; ["lo";"co";"mo";"lo";"co";"mo"]]
```

I've been running in circles around this one. If I'm not mistaken, I know that my 'if expression' should revolve around something related to the length of the lists within a list, and when it is `List.length mod 2 = 1` the sub-list should concatenate with itself.

But, I'm unable to apply it as I've never worked with list of lists! How should this function be written? Your help is much appreciated.

EDIT 1:

I've tried to do the following

```
let double_list l = l@l;;
let rec oddleninLdbl l =
if l = [] 
then []
else (
let t = List.tl l in
  if ((List.length l) mod 2 = 1) 
  then double_list l
  else oddleninLdbl t
) ;;
```

but I'm getting this as an answer :

```
# oddleninLdbl [[]; [5]; [23;5]; [45;65;2]; []; [34;85;7;22;1]] ;;
- : int list list =
[[5]; [23; 5]; [45; 65; 2]; []; [34; 85; 7; 22; 1]; [5]; [23; 5]; [45; 65; 2]; []; [34; 85; 7; 22; 1]]

# oddleninLdbl [[]; ["mi";"lo"]; ["la"]; ["lo";"co";"mo"]] ;;
- : string list list =
[["mi"; "lo"]; ["la"]; ["lo"; "co"; "mo"]; ["mi"; "lo"]; ["la"];["lo"; "co"; "mo"]]

# oddleninLdbl [5;6;3;4;6] ;;
- : int list = [5; 6; 3; 4; 6; 5; 6; 3; 4; 6]
# oddleninLdbl [4;5] ;;
- : int list = [5; 5]
# oddleninLdbl [4;5;8] ;;
- : int list = [4; 5; 8; 4; 5; 8]
# oddleninLdbl [4;5;8;9] ;;
- : int list = [5; 8; 9; 5; 8; 9]
# oddleninLdbl ["mi";"lo"] ;;
- : string list = ["lo"; "lo"]
# oddleninLdbl ["mi";"lo";"co"] ;;
- : string list = ["mi"; "lo"; "co"; "mi"; "lo"; "co"]
# oddleninLdbl ["mi"] ;;
- : string list = ["mi"; "mi"]
```

Clearly not what is expected of this function to do. Where is the culprit in my code? Could someone give me their diagnosis?

EDIT 2 :

```
let double_list l = (List.hd l)@(List.hd l);;
let p l = (List.length (List.hd l)) mod 2 = 1 ;;
let apply p double_list l = 
  let rec aux acc l = match l with
  | [] -> List.rev acc
  | hd :: tl -> 
    let hd = if p hd then double_list hd else hd in
    aux (hd :: acc) tl ;;
```

I am getting syntax error on this one surely I've skipped something here. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good rule of thumb when working with structures that you can't easily understand is to divide and conquer.

Your problem, here, can be decomposed in multiple parts:

1. Take a list of list and return a list of lists
2. When a list is odd, double it

So, you should first create a simple function that doubles a list

```ml
let double_list l = (* double the elements in a list of elements *)
```

Then you should create a function that traverses a list of elements and does something when the current element correspond to a predicate `p`

```ml
let apply p f l = 
  let rec aux acc l = match l with
  | [] -> List.rev acc
  | hd :: tl -> 
    let hd = if p hd then f hd else hd in
    aux (hd :: acc) tl
  in aux [] l
```

Now the only thing you need is the proper predicate `p` and you already implemented your function `f` and it should work perfectly.

To summarize, never be afraid of an apparent complexity when you can just simplify your problem by dividing it in smaller problems.

EDIT:

Here is your code:

```ml
let double_list l = l@l;;

let rec oddleninLdbl l =
  if l = [] 
  then []
  else (
    let t = List.tl l in
    if ((List.length l) mod 2 = 1) 
    then double_list l
    else oddleninLdbl t
) ;;
```

This is not idiomatic OCaml, try to use pattern-matching instead:

```ml
let double_list l = l@l;;

let rec oddleninLdbl l =
  match l with
  | [] -> [] 
  | hd :: tl ->
    if ((List.length l) mod 2 = 1) 
    then double_list l
    else oddleninLdbl tl;;
```

As you can see, you're checking if `l` is odd, not its element, which is not what you want to do. You want to check if `hd` is odd and double it then keep traversing the rest of the list and append `hd` (doubled or not) to the result of the recursive call. Here, when `l` is odd you double it and stop and if it's not you just forget the head of the list and double the rest (since the rest will logically be an odd list).

Comment: I've followed your tip @Lhooq, decomposed my problem into multiple parts in the edit above. I'm trying to understand this language as a self-learner and would like to get some feedback on my mistakes.

Comment: Of course, shoot and I'll try to answer ;-)

Comment: Whenever you'll have a moment, I've edited my post above normally it should appear under EDIT 1 section.

Comment: I did the amendments needed and it worked ! I've replaced l by its hd in the first function. Then, replaced l with its head in the second part of my second function. I also made it traverse the rest of the list recursively at the end like so, for the first case double_list l :: oddleninLdbl tl then the second case and it worked ! All my appreciation for this explanation !

Comment: You're welcome. Now look again at my `apply` function to make your function tail recursive (by using an accumulator). In your case it's really not hard ;-)

Comment: I'm looking into the `apply` function suggested now. I'm not sure how tail rec would work, but if I understand well p _the predicate_ is a type bool right ? and well I'd replace `f` with `double_list` am I somewhat near with my interpretation?

Comment: `p` is a predicate so in your case it should be a function that says if a list is odd or not but you can get rid of it and just inline it where it is used (like you do in your function).

Comment: I've added a second edit in my original post trying to figure this tail rec story now... any thoughts?

Comment: That's my fault, I forgot to add `in aux [] l` in the end ;-) But your `double_list` and `p` functions are wrong, you're already giving them the internal list so you don't need to use `List.hd`

Comment: `let p l = (List.length l) mod 2 = 1 ;;`

Comment: `let double_list l = l@l ;; `

Comment: `let apply p f l = 
  let rec aux acc l = match l with
    | [] -> List.rev acc
    | hd :: tl -> 
        let hd = if p hd then f hd else hd in
        aux (hd :: acc) tl
  in aux [] l ;;`

Comment: `apply p double_list [[56;56;65;];[65;56;76;76];[67;87]] ;;
- : int list list = [[56; 56; 65; 56; 56; 65]; [65; 56; 76; 76]; [67; 87]]` all good now it worked even with this method, thanks again for the explanation !